# Strapi GraphQL - Security (header bearer_token)

Tags: angular, graphql, strapi

Is there a way to secure GraphQL queries in Strapi?

I'm developing an application in Angular 6 (frontend) and Strapi (backend). Ideally, i'd like to only allow queries with an authorised bearer_token.

Cheers, Rodrigo

Comment: Strapi is a headless CMS written in Node. Just add some auth middleware to validate specific endpoints.

Comment: @KarolTrybulec you're right, it is a headless cms, however, that is not what i'm asking. Currently standard routes do validate the bearer_token according to roles (beautiful). I'm looking to achieve the same via the graphql implementation.

Have you created middleware for the GraphQL implementation? if so, can you share an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Users and Permissions section of the admin panel is based on the controllers' actions, not of routes. Because default GraphQL queries use these actions, you can use the Users & Permissions section to manage GraphQL security rules.

If you want to add more custom logic or secure your custom GraphQL resolvers, take a look a this section of the documentation: https://strapi.io/documentation/guides/graphql.html#execute-a-policy-before-a-resolver.

Comment: I can execute deleteUser mutation without any auth. Shouldnt that be secured by default?

Comment: @ivoba you can control this from "Roles & Permissions. Select "Public" then assign the required permissions for public documents/endpoints.